# git remote master branch not synced with local branch

Tags: git

> git push origin master

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unable to resolve reference refs/heads/master: Permission denied
remote: error: failed to lock refs/heads/master
To git@remote-repository
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to lock)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@remote-repository'
```

Previously there was no problem with this command. Does power shutdown while executing the command gives problem like this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the poweroff left the remote in an inconsistent state.

Have you tried to `git push -f origin master`?

`-f` will tell git to push even if that may overwrite things. This may be dangerous in general, but in this case it is probably OK since you want to force the server to a particular correct state.

Comment: Have you googled for "git failed to lock"? None of the suggestions helped? The simplest thing to do might be to just destroy the remote and push again if you can do that.

Comment: Dont know how, but resetting the server and reset to the previous commit makes it work for now